# the declare scope of loop

Tags: c++, scope

Can anyone explain to me, why the below codes have different output?

```
void GenerateMatrix(int mat[][MaxSize],int ran[],const int rows,const int cols)  
{   
    int i,k=0;
    while (i<rows)
    {
        int j=0;
        while (j<cols)
        {
            mat[i][j]=ran[k];          
            j,k++;
        }
        i++;    
    }
}
```

and the correct one

```
void GenerateMatrix(int mat[][MaxSize],int ran[],const int rows,const int cols)
{
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<rows;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<cols;j++)
        {
        mat[i][j]=ran[k];
        k++;
        }
    }
}
```

the ran[] is an array declared in main()

```
int main()
{
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]={(rand() % 20-0+1)+1};
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

the first one always output strange random numbers, not in the range of random numbers I set for a[] in main().
The second one is correct.
I have change the scope of declaration of k in the first one function, still the same. I'm just wondering witch part result in this?

Comment: What do you intend `j,k++;` to do? Did you debug to observe whether the variables change as you intended?

Comment: `int i, k = 0` is equivalent to `int i; int k = 0` so `i` is uninitialized when you are accessing it, triggering undefined behavior. You probably meant `int i = 0, k = 0`.

Comment: Also `j,k++` is equivalent to `k++` (assuming the evaluation of `j` doesn't have side-effects), not a very useful statement.

Comment: Thanks, I had always thought I can declared two integers at the same time..., and is there a better way instead `j,k++` if I want to increase both counter variables at the same time?

Comment: Err, `j++; k++;`?

Comment: The comma operator combines a sequence of smaller sub expressions into one single concatenated expression. That can be useful in cases you need to perform some test after a modification that doesn't itself provide a result, such as `void modify(int& x); void demo() { for(int i = 0; modify(i), i < 7; ) { } }`, but that's rarely used. The value of the entire expression always is the value of the very last sub-expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be following a "spoken English" approach to using the `,`, like "do something to this list of variables". In this reading, the initialisation failure (where it does create a list other than you mean; spotted by CherryDT) and the incrementation failure (caused by misuse as comma operator; spotted by two commenters, including me) can be "read".
I propose to change that by reading up on the "comma operator" and reviewing some tutorials on other uses of ",".
Consider reducing/avoiding the use altogether, it is too dangerous for your coding habits.

Comment: For reference, it's called "comma operator".

Comment: @CherryDT not in all the problematic cases. Also, I believe that referring to it that way is not helpful to OP. But I will add it for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: I just meant it's hard to google a literal comma. But you are right, in case of the initialization issue it has nothing to do with that operator.

Comment: @CherryDT True.

Comment: Unrelated: yes, you are correct. Kudos for being the first one to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

In the first function you have *two* errors:

1. The statement

   ```
   int i,k=0;
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   int i;
   int k=0;
   ```

   This means that `i` is *uninitialized* and will have an *indeterminate* value.

   You need to explicitly initialize it as well:

   ```
   int i = 0, k = 0;
   ```
2. The second error is the statement:

   ```
   j,k++;
   ```

   This is equivalent to

   ```
   j;
   k++;
   ```

   That is, it evaluates the left-hand side of [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) (i.e. `j`) and then throws away the result. Then it evaluates and returns the result of the right-hand side (i.e. `k++`).

   You need to increment both variables:

   ```
   j++;
   k++;
   ```

Or you can use the `for` loops which are more compact, still as readable, and harder to make such mistakes as in the first function.